# access to elements of an array in js vs hashtable in c++ or c# performance?

Tags: javascript

js uses a hash table to access to elements of an array. So is it slower than the method of accessing array elements in c++ or c# languages?

```
var arr=[];
arr[0]=23;
arr[1]=12;
arr['2tr5']=54;
```

Is the algorithm that accesses to elements of an array in js the same as hashtable in c++ or c#?
How can we speed up to access to elements directly and why doesn't js use dense array with fast access to elements.

Comment: "*why doesn't js use dense array with fast access to elements*" Take a look at what [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#Buffers_and_views_typed_array_architecture) are.

Comment: thank you, it is perfect. read and write from/to typed array is so fast? and do I say correctly about normal array in js is hashtable?